# Formula for calculation score based on distance

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials

I try to write function for calculating scoring from distance in my game.

I found something similar : 
[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4500%2aexp%28-x%5E2%2F%282%2a200000%29%29+%2B+2000%2aexp%28-x%5E2%2F%282%2a20000000%29%29+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D20000+and+y%3D0+to+y%3D7000)

But I need the distance(x) to be between 0-31855000 meters and score between 0 to 1000.

Thanks for Help!

Comment: What shape do you want your function to have? You could simply use a linear scaled version so: $$\operatorname{score}(\text{distance})=\frac{\text{distance}}{31855}$$

Comment: Hi, I don`t want it to be linear, like on the example I found, I want that after 1000 meters you get much less points.

Comment: In that case my suggestion would be to devise some $n$ known points (including $\text{distance}=0 \implies \text{score}=0$ and $\text{distance}=31855000\implies \text{score}=1000$ and then use an $n-1$ degree [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Comment: I want distance=0 ==> score=1000 and distance=31855000 ==> score=0.
Link to Wikipedia didn`t help me.